# Debugging parallel python and SCOOP interactively

Tags: python, debugging, zeromq, mpi4py

I have come from a background of debugging **`mpi4py`** code interactively such that the python instance experienced by each of the different CPUs is displayed in a different instance of an **`xterm`** window. Following the advice at the link below, I have been able to execute my code using a command such as `$mpirun -np 4 xterm -e "ipython -i script.py"`, which I learned from the following source: [debugging **`mpi4py`** interactively](https://bfroehle.com/2011/09/14/debugging-mpi-python/)

Executing parallel python code in this manner means that if I insert break points with `pdb.set_trace()`, bugs in the code that relate to the context of a each single processor become very transparent, and this approach greatly facilitates monkey patching.

I have now moved from `mpi4py` to **`SCOOP`**, and I am wondering if there is any similar way that I can launch the python processors corresponding to different CPUs in different `xterm` instances? The reason for the switch is because now I am using a python module **`DEAP`**, which is designed to work well with `SCOOP`.

Also I am wondering if the Wakari **`IPcluster`** approach can be combined with `SCOOP` or `mpi4py` as well?

**`Note:`** I added the tag `ZeroMQ` as I believe that `SCOOP` is built on top of `ZeroMQ`.